# Excel Template Show Associated Tasks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I found a template in excel 2013 called "Weekly Time Planner". It has a mechanism that filters another table when clicking upon a certain item. For example, I select one project in the project overview and it shows me all tasks asociated with that project. I have difficulty finding out how this template implements this functionality. I'm trying to create a similair sheet to register time worked on a specific task.

Comment: I believe we need more info to offer up any advice on how to do this. Does your template contain VBA? Can you post the template?

Comment: It's a standard template called weekly time planner that comes with excel 2013, it does not contain VBA